# Calculate seasonal price from mongodb documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection like this in mongodb:

```js
{
    product: 1,
    basePrice: 100,
    seasonalPrices: [{
        fromDate: 2017 - 10 - 17 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        toDate: 2017 - 10 - 18 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        delta: 10,
        isIncrease: true
    }, {
        fromDate: 2017 - 10 - 19 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        toDate: 2017 - 10 - 20 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        delta: 10,
        isIncrease: false
    }]
}, {
    product: 2,
    basePrice: 200,
    seasonalPrices: [{
        fromDate: 2017 - 10 - 17 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        toDate: 2017 - 10 - 18 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        delta: 10,
        isIncrease: true
    }, {
        fromDate: 2017 - 10 - 19 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        toDate: 2017 - 10 - 20 18: 30: 00.000 Z,
        delta: 10,
        isIncrease: false
    }]
}
```

This collection contains product information along with its base and seasonal price. Here seasonalPrices field is array with fromDate, ToDate, delta ( % of increase or decrease) and isIncrease field which shows increase in seasonal Price if it is true.

I need two queries for this collection

1. Query which will return calculated seasonal price if it exists ( else show base price) for per product along  with its basic details  This query will be called during product listing.
2. I want to categorize product based on prices (on seasonal prices)
   which I 
       will show in product filter page. query something like this :

```js
 "categorizedByPrice": [
        // Filter out documents without a price e.g., _id: 7
        { $match: { price: { $exists: 1 } } },
        {
          $bucket: {
            groupBy: "$price",
            boundaries: [  0, 150, 200, 300, 400 ],
            default: "Other",
            output: {
              "count": { $sum: 1 },
              "titles": { $push: "$title" }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

But should be on calculated seasonal price.

I'm new to mongodb and getting difficulties to write these mongodb queries. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for help!

Comment: Whats the formula for calculating seasonal price?

Comment: Calculate % of basePrice using delta given in seasonalPrices and add or subtract(by using isIncrease field) it with basePrice .

Comment: You need to $unwind if you want to access the fields inside the array.

Comment: Also to what do your field names refer to? what is price and/or title in your example?

Comment: @AlexP. Above one is just an example I took it from MongoDB docs for aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/ . It is one example for $bucket. My problem here is I want to perform this aggregation on calculated seasonal price.